# Emulating an HiDpi display

Tags: x11, wayland, high-dpi

I have a low res laptop (1366x768) and I want to see how an app performs on a high res display. Is it possible to emulate a high res display on linux. Theoretically it should be possible. The X server will broadcast the display as 4k, the apps will paint according to that and the xserver will downsize the frame before painting it on real hardware. How do I go about implementing it? Can wayland do that?